# Postgres locale error on remote server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ubuntu, locale

I am using a remote server from Digital Ocean set up with Ubuntu 14.04, Rails and am having issues with missing locale settings. I have googled the issue and have tried them which didn't work for me.

### Examples

```
sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

### Error received when trying to create a new Postgres user

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = (unset),
LC_ALL = (unset),
LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C")
```

### My -locale settings

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or   directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your LANGUAGE is not set.

You can try

```
export LANGUAGE="en_US.UTF-8"
echo 'LANGUAGE="en_US.UTF-8"' >> /etc/default/locale
echo 'LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"' >> /etc/default/locale
```

This is nice article about how to [configure locale in Ubuntu](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Configure_Locales_in_Ubuntu).

---

Edit: I noticed now it is about Digital Ocean. Try to edit environment instead

```
gksudo gedit /etc/environment
```

and add `LANGUAGE="en_US.UTF-8"` and `LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"`. I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the locales problem before:

http://andreas.scherbaum.la/blog/archives/272-locales-on-Ubuntu.html